# Display a tables value when a record is not empty

Tags: php, mysql

I have an activity table that contain the list of activity student had joined before. So if the student is new student, there will have been no activity for that student.

```html
<table align="center" width="1000" border="1" >
  <h3>Activity List</h3>
    </br>
    
    <tr align="center" style="font-weight:bold" >
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Activity</td>
    <td>Sem</td>
    <td>Session</td>
    <td>Achievement</td>
    <td>Level</td>
  </tr>
  <?php do { ?>
    <tr align="center">
      <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['student_id']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['activity']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['sem']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['session']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['achievement']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['level']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
</table>
```

How can I make this table only show on screen if it is not empty. Btw, im using session to display the exist record.

Comment: In php use if(!empty) for your variable.

Comment: Can you post your code? Not much we can do without seeing what you have tried.

Comment: Hide the table from what?

Comment: Hi yaya, welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately your question doesn't make it easy for us to help you. We can't see your code so we don't know how to hide it. You need to include your code in your question. I'd also recommend you read SO's [how to ask a good question guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Try to avoind a `do { /*do this code*/ } while (true);` in your code as they are someone useless, the best thing is to do `while (condition) { /*do this code*/ }`. A do while uses somewhat more processing power and is slightly less reliable I have found.

Comment: Could you also show us a general idea of the query you are using to fill the variable `$Recordset1`?

Comment: @yaya, have you had any luck yet friend?

Comment: Just a quick one to add, you have used a hard code style value of `1000px` for your table width, is this for a specific reason or do you not know about the percent width values you can use? (That probably sounds very patronising which it isn't meant to, I assure you)

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this would be to get your array via `mysql(i)_fetch_array()` of the query you have build and then to chec to see if the query has rows like:

```
$qry = "SELECT `this` FROM `table`"
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        echo "We have rows!";
    }
    else {
        echo "Looks like we haven't got anything here!";
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Might also help to look here: [PHP mysql_num_rows method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if(!empty($activity))
{
your msg ..
}
else
{
}
?>
```

where `empty()` will check a given variable is empty or not

Comment: The would not work well at all because the `empty()` function also checks to see if the variable is set or not, so in theory you could have `if (empty($randomUnsetVar)) { /*returns true*/ }` because it believes the variable is empty even though it is not set. Please see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) for the description

Comment: Great idea, just flawed.

Answer (score 1):

Well that's what the if statement is used for:

```
if(!count($activities)) {
echo "This student has no activities yet.";
} else {
//display activities
....
}
```

Comment: The count function works for arrays, so you would have to do a fetch_array on the query first to do what you are suggesting (e.g.: `if (count(mysql_fecth_array($activities_query)) === 0) { ... }`

Comment: yes that's correct, when i answered this the op still hadn't posted the code snippet

Comment: But the problem is, you said `if(!count($activities))`, where `count()` never returns false,it can only return int, so your answer would be misleading because you would have to do `if (count($activities)) === 0}`

Comment: Even `count(null)` returns 0

Comment: Try this and see the result:
$arr = array();

if(count($arr))
{
  echo "ok";
} else {
  echo "no";
}
basically !count($arr) is same as count($arr) === 0